# Software tool to sniff WiFi from misconfigured IOT client device on any platform

Tags: wifi, iot

When setting up a smart switch with Sonoff tasmota, I goofed and mistyped the SSID and/or passwd.

Is there a way to see what SSID the IOT device is trying to contact by “looking“ at the communications with some sort of sniffer?

The network password won't matter since it will be a temporarily wide open wifi network to "rescue" the iot device.

Answer (score 1):

Fix for a bad SSID on a sonoff tasmota device.

I used a raspberry pi with wifi for these steps. Your mileage may vary.

1. sudo apt install aircrack-ng wireshark-gtk
2. Good idea to reboot now
3. Disconnect from any wifi networks. Disconnect from any wired networks.
4. sudo airmon-ng check kill
   This will kill wpa supplicant and a couple of other processes.
5. Repeat step 4 to verify nothing running.
6. sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
   This will create a 'new' interface wlan0mon that will be used by wireshark
7. xhost +
   This will allow root to run programs on the X11 client
8. sudo wireshark-gtk
9. start wireshark monitor for wlan0mon interface
   This will capture data from the wifi interface
10. Plug in the smart switch( or activate whatever device is unknown )
11. let wireshark capture for 10 seconds or so.
12. Stop wireshark capture.
13. Sort wireshark by the source column to find sources beginning with Espressif
14. The info column will begin with "Probe Request", and the erroneous SSID 
    that the device wants to connect to will be the final portion
    of the info column.
15. I set up a spare wifi router with the SSID set to what was found
    above and disabled all security. Bear in mind this open network 
    will only be running for a short time. DO NOT connect this router to
    any network.
16. Connect any other device to the router that can open web pages.
17. open web page or admin program for the router and find the ip address
    for the device.
18. open the web page for the device using the ip address above and
    reconfigure the device for the correct network name.
19. sudo airmon-ng stop wlan0
    this will disable the wlan0mon interface needed by wireshark.
20. disconnect the raspberry pi from the temporary router.
21. poweroff the temporary router.
22. reboot the raspberry pi to remove any monitor leftovers.
23. You should now have control back over the device.

Comment: I signed up just to say thank you for the Fix. This was VERY useful and really saved me.